# Practical to measure topography of a large area (mm-scale) with scanning probe microscopy (SPM)?

Tags: microscopy, nanoscience, experimental-technology

I'm currently very new to nanotechnology. I do understand that it is possible to achieve an excellent topography image of a sample by SPM. However, is it possible to do SPM over a large area (for instance like in SEM, which is possible to image over 1x1 mm)? Theoretically speaking, I do not see any problem except that measurement time might be very high.

So, is it possible to scan over a large area (mm-scale)? If not, what can the reason be if one excluded measurement time. If yes, which technique will give an advantage for such measurement?

I would appreciate if anyone could explain the theory/mechanism behind this or point me to a place where I can obtain a better understanding.

Comment: Cross posted in Chemistry SE

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/151986/

Comment: These days people are developing arrays of probe tips to decrease time to acquire data over large samples. One recent paper is https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/5.0015897 using 7 tips and capable of scanning over 25mm x 25mm.